# Polymorphism in Rust. AsRef vs Deref

Tags: rust, polymorphism, parameter-passing

I want to create a function that can take as an argument `String`, `&str`, `Rc<String>`, `Arc<String>`, etc. `String` is just an example, the parameter can be of any type. I can do this using `AsRef`:

```
fn is_empty_as_ref<T: AsRef<str>>(arg1: T) -> bool {
  arg1.as_ref().is_empty()
}
```

Or `Deref`:

```
fn is_empty_deref<T: Deref<Target = str>>(arg1: T) -> bool {
  arg1.is_empty()
}
```

In my playground, both of these approaches work well. So I have 3 questions:

1. In general, without any specific case, what trait should I use for such polymorphism?
2. In which cases should I use one instead of the other?
3. Are there other commonly used traits for that kind of polymorphism? (I don't need it, but maybe I'm missing something)

Comment: *"In my playground, both of these approaches work well"* - uhhh, what? `Rc<String>` and `Arc<String>` do NOT implement `Deref<Target = str>` so I'm not sure why you think that works for your premise. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=09d7c0f2f5bc4f927f71c0218de9f4ea). I guess you did say its an example but that's a shaky foundation for a question.

Comment: @kmdreko I can do `is_empty_deref(Rc::new(String::from("")).as_str())`. Yes, I know that I'm passing `&str`, not `Rc`. Maybe "that's a shaky foundation for a question". After Masklinn’s answer, I understand that my question and example are pretty silly, but it may not be obvious to rust learners (like me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> String is just an example, the parameter can be of any type.

It can not, actually. Because there is no `impl AsRef<T> for T`. So for most types, `AsRef` will not let you pass in an owned value.

> In general, without any specific case, what trait should I use for such polymorphism?

In general, none of the above, request an `&T` and let the caller handle the conversion. Notably if they have a `Deref<Target=T>` they can just call

```
do_thing(&value)
```

and deref coercion will handle the rest.

> In which cases should I use one instead of the other?

I don't believe there's anything clear-cut. The documentation for `AsRef` has various notes and furthermore covers the case of `Borrow`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html

Generally speaking, `Deref` is what's implemented by *smart pointers*, to allow accessing their pointees. "Smart pointer" is itself a somewhat fuzzy concept, usually designated by the ability to be Deref'd, and notably does not mean "transparent wrapper" since e.g. `String` or `Vec` are smart pointers.

In the stdlib, `AsRef` is used to cheaply convert to broader / less restrictive types *with the same underlying structure* e.g. strings (of all kinds) to `OsStr` or `Path`, as a `String` is more restrictive than the other two, and thus any string is also a valid OsStr / Path. In an **extremely limited** way, `AsRef` acts a bit like an inheritance system.

Finally `Borrow` is more specific to maps, in some ways it's a more restrictive than `AsRef` as it has additional requirements (specifically that the Borrow-ed reference has hashing, equality, and ordering matching the original), but it *is* implemented for `T`. So `Borrow` has a two-way substitutability implication, it considers that the borrowed and the borrowee are equivalent but for ownership, which is not the case of `AsRef`.

> Are there other commonly used traits for that kind of polymorphism?

What kind of polymorphism? Internally specific but externally generic parameters? From/Into and TryFrom/TryInto are probably the most common.